# Using 'cd' in terminal prints syntax error

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm getting extra output on the command line when changing directories in terminal. The output is:

```
Casey-MacBook-Pro:~ casey$ cd Envs
-bash: command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
-bash: command substitution: line 9: `    done'
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:Envs casey$
```

Any idea on what is causing this? Could it be something in my bash profile? This is what my bash profile looks like when I run subl ~/.bash_profile:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-02_at_20:37:40: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/activate.sh

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-09-24_at_12:31:24: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID=""
export STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET=""
export SENDGRID_API_KEY=""
export SECRET_KEY=""
export FLASK_CONFIG=""
export DEV_DATABASE_URL=""
export TEST_DATABASE_URL=""

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: What does `type cd` show?

Comment: It shows this: cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    autoenv_cd "$@"
}

Comment: Does one of the files `~/Envs/.env` or `~/.env` exist? If so, could you add their contents to the question?

Comment: The directory ~/Envs exists but the file .env does not. I tried to edit it and it was a new file.

Comment: Well either way, you seem to have [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) installed, and either the autoenv script itself, or a script that gets loaded by it is broken. Contents of `/usr/local/bin/activate.sh`?

Comment: Well I'm not using autoenv so I think I'll just remove it. When I look at /usr/local/bin/activate.sh, it contains cd() {
  autoenv_cd "$@"
} at the bottom

Comment: It also includes autoenv_cd()
{
  if builtin cd "$@"
  then
    autoenv_init
    return 0
  else
    return $?
  fi
}

Comment: Might be a dependency for something else you installed though. Are you using homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is that `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is redefining `cd` into something broken.

Try commenting these out from `~/.bash_profile` and opening a new Terminal window.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/activate.sh
```